# Is it possible to load object with all lazy properties without a iteration?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have an object which has children, some of which loaded lazy some not. Now I have situation where I need a parent object to load with all the child at once. Is there quick way to do this without checking `Hibernate.isInitialized()` on all the properties?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would use `Hibernate.initialze(..)`, but you can also serialize the object (using `ObjectOutputStream` or `XMLEncoder`. The serialization mechanism will iterate all properties and they will be initialized. You can use commons-lang `SerializationUtils`.

Comment: thanx for the reply, but for Hibernate.initialize(property) i still must give a property which is what i would like to avoid. Serialization thing might work,. tho it seems kind of a hack workaround to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

How are you obtaining the object?

A general approach to this (it's often called 'hydration' of the objects) is to ask for a join fetch. That's where the ORM retrieves the data for the child objects at the same time as the data for the parent by using a join, and uses the data to eagerly initialize the children.

There are various ways to ask for a join fetch, mostly provider-specific, but you can [write it into portable JPQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/kodo41/full/html/ejb3_langref.html#ejb3_langref_fetch_joins):

```
select p from Parent p join fetch p.children where ...
```

However, note that this will return each parent multiple times - as many as it has children. That's a bit weird, but it's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Tom, I use fetch joins to bring back child objects that I want initialized.  As far as the query bringing back multiple Parent objects, I believe adding a "DISTINCT" clause should fix that.